# Node.js. What should I use? Next()?

Tags: node.js

```
app.get("/server", function (req, res){
    connection.query("SELECT * from serverdb", function(err, rows)
    {
    var data = rows;
    var reachabilityResultString="";
    var serverCount = rows.length;
    var arrayWithReachabilityResultStrings = new Array();
    var insertReachabilityResultStringIntoArray;
        for (var counterForServername = 0 ; counterForServername < serverCount; counterForServername++)
        {

            ls = childProcess.exec('ping ' + rows[counterForServername].ipadresse,function (error, stdout, stderr) 
            {
                if (error) 
                {
                     console.log(error.stack);
                     console.log('Error code: '+error.code);
                     console.log('Signal received: '+error.signal);
                     var errorSignal = ("Signal received: " + error.signal);
                     var errorReachability = "Error";

                }
                else
                {
                    console.log('Child Process STDOUT: '+stdout);
                    console.log('Child Process STDERR: '+stderr);
                    pingOutput = String(stdout);

                    console.log(reachabilityResult(pingOutput));

                    insertReachabilityResultStringIntoArray = arrayWithReachabilityResultStrings.push(reachabilityResult(pingOutput));
                    console.log(arrayWithReachabilityResultStrings);
                };

            ls.on('exit', function (code) {
            console.log('Child process exited with exit code '+code);

            });

            });
        };
    });
res.render("all.jade,{servers: data, status: arrayWithReachabilityResultStrings});
});
```

..well..this is my code. My problem is that the program first invoke the website with the jadecode; I hope you know what I mean. I want to deliver the `arrayWithReachabilityResultStrings` to `all.jade`, so the program must wait until the for loop is finished. But I don't know how to make it wait. I know the "problem" is the asynchronous behavior of node.js but I don't know how I can solve this..

Comment: Btw I must use mysql..

Answer (score 1):

just fix your missing " and move your

`res.render("all.jade,{servers: data, status: arrayWithReachabilityResultStrings});`

one line up. It needs to be invoked by a callback in connection.query, as it is now it is invoked much sooner.
It would also be nice, if you read a bit about javascript variable scoping. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) does good job in that.

P.S.: Glad to see new people learning node.

Comment: Yeah, if you want to execute render after all ping commands execute, you make sure that all of them are executed. There are several ways to do that-I would use a simple counter. Start at 0 and with each finished ping increase by 1 and check if counter equals "serverCount" then you know all previous pings are completed. Doownside to this "counting" is that if you forget to call it, it will never complete.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run an arbitrary number of subcommands and wait until they are all done, you should consider a helper library such as async.js and use the async.queue flow control function. This kind of coordination is actually somewhat tricky in node to code by hand without any flow control facilities. However, it is certainly possible. In this case you would need a separate `done` counter that you increment on each 'exit' event and when all of your child processes have been started and all have finished, you're done.

Comment: async.js is installed now..and which Control Flow module should I use?  timesSeries?

Comment: Looking briefly at your code, it looks like you should use `async.queue`. Start with a limit of 1 as you get things working, and once you are clear and confident, you can increase the limit to something higher like 10.